# Referenced Spring XSD file contains errors in JBoss Developer Studio

Tags: java, xml, spring, jboss, xsd

I have an application which is using Jboss and being developed in JBoss Developer Studio and I am using Spring Security.

Suddenly the IDE started showing up an error in applicationContext.xml complaining that the referenced file contains errors.

Everything is configured to use java 1.7 and I don't see why that happens.

Does anybody has any idea what is going on here?

I am attaching an screen shot of the problem here.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved changing this:

```
<beans:beans xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
```

With this:

```
<beans xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
```

Comment: Did you also find an explanation for why this solves your problem?

Comment: Nope, the error just disappeared, it must be something related to Java 1.7 and Spring version 4.0